# How to give message when user try to type alphabets in Number using extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to send message when user try to enter alphabets in number filed of extjs. My code is as follow:

```
txtDecDHR = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Number', {
    width: 320,
    hideTrigger: true,
    keyNavEnabled: false,
    mouseWheelEnabled: false,
    value:'10.69',
    labelWidth: 100,
    style: {
            marginLeft: '10px',
                marginTop: '2px'
        },
    fieldLabel: 'Number*',
});
```

please help me for same

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the example.

Ext.onReady(function(){

txtDecDHR = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Number',

{

```
width: 320,

hideTrigger: true,

enableKeyEvents:true,

keyNavEnabled: false,

mouseWheelEnabled: false,

 listeners:{

    keyup:function( field, event ){

           var keyNum=parseInt(event.getCharCode());

           if(keyNum>47 && keyNum <58 || keyNum>95 && keyNum<106 ){

               alert("Number");

             }
                else{
               alert("alphabet or special character");


               }

          }

    },

value:'10.69',

renderTo:document.body,

labelWidth: 100,

style: {

        marginLeft: '10px',

            marginTop: '2px'

    },

fieldLabel: 'Number*'
```

});

});

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS numberfield is already designed to prevent entering non-numerical values. Thus, the only letter that you can enter is E, because it is allowed to enter something like 10E38 (which is then translated into 10^38). However, this way you can trick the number field and leave just E, which of course is not a valid numerical value. Default message in that case is '**The value in this field is invalid**', which can be changed by setting the value of the property `invalidText`.

See also:

- [ExtJS documentation (numberfield)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-invalidText)